# itertools combinations function crashes computer - need 25*10^12 combos

Tags: python, statistics, anaconda, data-science

Using Python 3.5.2 on a Linux machine. I have 185 distinct strings in a CSV that I read in using pandas. I then use itertools to run all the combinations choosing 8 out of the distinct strings: 185 choose 8. Here is the code:

```
names1 = ['player_name', 'blank_column']

data2 = pd.read_csv('LU_4FEB_DFSBB_10GS.csv', names=names1, usecols=[0])

print(data2)

combos = list(it.combinations(data2.player_name, 8))
print(combos)
```

As soon as I run it, while watching task manager, pegs out 16 GB of memory, pegs out the 4 cores, and then I get this message inside the Spyder IDE:

> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.

I've run pretty big n choose r functions in Java and didn't run into these problems.

Comment: Why are you making a list of all of those combinations? The benefit of `itertools` is that it makes *iterators*, you don't have to consume them all into memory at once.

Comment: Please note, I have been coding in Python for a total of three days now.  Still learning the language.  I wanted it as a list so I could then run more functions on the resulting combinations.  I think you are saying that me doing that is less than optimal.  So I should just get rid of the list portion?

Comment: Well do you actually need all combinations available simultaneously? If not, you could take one at a time to work on: `for combo in it.combinations(data2.player_name, 8): ...`.

Comment: Well, I could run some logic on each result, toss a combination that isn't valid.  Store a valid combination into a list.  If there is a better container to use than a list that's fine too.

Comment: Even if you don't materialize the list and just iterate over them one by one the way anticipated by the itertools module, 185 choose 8 is *way* more combinations (~3e13, by my count) than you'll be able to process quickly.  Unless you only need to handle the first few of these to do whatever it is you want (or each action is very quick, I guess) I expect you're in for disappointment.

Comment: i suspect it is the print() function crashes the computer. could you try save the results on disk? but there are altogether 30 trillion of combinations, the list could have overwhelmed. maybe the java solution you mention iterates the results when it comes to the time to output to display or file

Comment: I can be more concrete about my performance concerns.  It takes me 168 ms just to do `sum(1 for c in islice(combinations(range(185), 8), 10**6))`.  This means it would take about (3e13/1e6 * 0.168) / (3600 * 24) ~ 58 days *just to count them*.

Comment: So, this is the same type of function hackers use to perform a brute force attack to find somebody's password.  So it is possible to do.  maybe i could represent each name in a row as a binary number?  That way it would represent a unique key?